# Please help to identify spaceship-like LEGO set

Tags: set-identification

It looks like the framework of a spaceship. Does anyone know what set it's in?

[image: Shaped like a letter T]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Between the blue pin and the grey plane nose bottom pieces there is a characteristic white wedge piece, which I have searched for. This piece exists in three different designs, each of which is only contained in sets that don't resemble anything like the build your image depicts:

- https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-4264027
- https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-4614247
- https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-6249584

On another path, I searched for the 2x2 brick with two balls, under the golden plate at the back, with the same results:

- https://brickset.com/sets/containing-design-17114/
- https://brickset.com/sets/containing-design-57908

So this leads me to think that your build is not part of any official sets, or it could be a somewhat modified part of a set.